# GoogleMaps is not a dylib : Error at compile time with pod file

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, ios8.3

Linker Error : 
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied: framework linker option at/Path /GoogleMaps is not a dylib

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:

objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

> Here i am using google places API with pod and Xocde 6.3 .
>   This issue is throwing at compile time when i am trying to use any of the class of the  **Google Maps** Frameworks .

Comment: Show your dependencies like in your podfile and mapView.

Comment: have you resolved it, I am facing the same issue?

Comment: I have removed pod file from my code . Actually i want to use Google Places API with Pod file but after getting this error , i had decided to direct API instead of whole framework and now its working same for me .

Comment: Tell me your requirement may be i ,ll short out that .

Comment: Simple Solution
Go to Target ->Linking -> other linker Flag and add $(inherited) in other linker flag in both Debug and Release.

Comment: @Mihir Oza Thank you so much

Comment: welcome. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same problem, I fix it with add the GoogleMaps.framework to Link Binary libraries. It fix and worked.

[image: All lib and framework in my project]